# Visual Studio visual bug

Tags: visual-studio

This one is a little hard to explain without a picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3an.png]

As you can see the window is all messed up. I tried to re-install VS and un-install ReSharper but nothing worked. I'm using VS 2015 Community. This is a really frustrating bug to work with, has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Are those release versions? Quote the version numbers of both.

Comment: 4.6.00079 Release. Of Both? Do you mean ReSharper too? In that picture I don't have ReSharper running so it's clearly not at fault. Either something to do with VS or my display driver.

Comment: 4.6.00079 is a .NET version. VS version should start with 15.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's 14.0.23107.0 D14REL